# android sqlite create statement not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

this code checks if a database exists and if not opens it and creates a table. but afterwards, trying to read from the table causes a no such table exception.

```
public class MuscleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SQLiteDatabase fitnessdb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_muscle);
    if (!getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("fitnessdb").exists()) ;
    {
        createDB();
    }
    Cursor resultSet = fitnessdb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM exercises", null);
    resultSet.moveToFirst();
    Log.d("stat", resultSet.getString(0));
}


public void createDB() {
    fitnessdb = openOrCreateDatabase("fitnessdb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    fitnessdb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \"exercices\" (\"_id\"\tINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,\"name\" TEXT,\"muscle_group\" TEXT,\"reps\" INTEGER,\"img1\"\tTEXT,\"img2\" TEXT,\"info\"\tTEXT);");
}
}
```

Comment: Try if removing the double quotes around the identifiers (table name, column names) in the `CREATE` or also adding them around the identifiers in the `SELECT` statement helps.

Comment: @stickybit now it's saying unknown error (code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN): Could not open database

Comment: Just to be sure: You didn't remove them around the argument `"fitnessdb"` for `getDatabasePath()` and/or `openOrCreateDatabase()`? Because there they are not interpreted by SQLite's SQL engine but by Java and are of course necessary. Just remove them in the `CREATE` statement and doing so don't forget to also remove the escaping `\`s in the string you pass the statement with.

Comment: @stickybit that's right

Comment: [Ormlite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml) is a great database wrapper for such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are aware of the typo in your query, but you spelled **exercises** as **exercices**.
Try fixing the typo and try again?

```
fitnessdb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \"exercises\" (\"_id\"\tINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,\"name\" TEXT,\"muscle_group\" TEXT,\"reps\" INTEGER,\"img1\"\tTEXT,\"img2\" TEXT,\"info\"\tTEXT);");
```